# Having a problem loading setting 'WEBGL' to the createCanvas() method in P5.js

Tags: angular, typescript, p5.js

I'm trying to load a 3D model with P5.js in Angular 8.  the syntax for creating a 3D canvas is

```
createCanvas(100, 100, WEBGL);
```

in Angular `WEBGL` is regarded as if it were a variable defined somewhere and throws this error.

> core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: WEBGL is not defined
>   ReferenceError: WEBGL is not defined

I tried modifying it like this

```
createCanvas(100, 100, 'WEBGL');
```

But when doing that I get this error

> p5.js says: createCanvas() was expecting P2D|WEBGL for parameter #2 (zero-based index), received string instead at...

which is indicating it wants a value without parenthesis.  How am I supposed to handle this?

***UPDATE***

I figured I'd share more code to be clearer about how I'm going about doing this.

I import the p5 library into the component like this

```
import * as p5 from 'p5';
```

inside my component I have a function that looks like this

```
private createGraphic(){
    const frameSize: any = this.calcFrameSize(); //calculates a width and height

    this.P5 = new p5(p =>{

            let importedModel: any;  //for pre loading the object

            p.preload = () =>{
                importedModel = p.loadModel(this.Element, true);
                //the this.Element variable is a string aiming to the .obj file
            }

            p.setup = () => {
                p.createCanvas(frameSize.width, frameSize.height, WEBGL); 
            };

            p.draw = () => {
                p.background(255, 17, 180);
                p.fill(0);
                p.scale(0.88);
                p.normalMaterial();
                p.model(importedModel);
            };
        },
        this.GraphicContainer.nativeElement
        //the target for injecting the object
        );
    }
```

I call this function inside the `ngOnInit()` like this

```
ngOnInit(){ this.createGraphic(); }
```

I tried using `this.WEBGL` as suggested in the answer bellow and am getting an error in the terminal saying

> WEBGL does not exist on type...

because it's searching for it on my component. I'm also getting this error in the console

> Error: normalMaterial() is only supported in WEBGL mode. If you'd like to use 3D graphics and WebGL,

I installed the `@types` library for P5.js to get it working with TypeScript.  I successfully got a 2D demo working and moved on to try 3D and am having these problems.

Comment: what exactly is the error when you use the first method?

Comment: I updated the post with the error.

Comment: how do you import the p5 library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it turns out all I needed to do was add `p` to it to keep it in scope.

```
p.createCanvas(frameSize.width, frameSize.height, p.WEBGL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to setup you process, but I assume you are using `p5.js` via the [instance method](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).

Your import needs to be:

```js
import p5 from "p5";
```

> For this import syntax to work and not throw an error, you need to set allowSyntheticDefaultImports (in compiler options) in tsconfig.json to true and have esModuleInterop set to true.

And you instantiate `p5` via:

```js
const myp5 = new p5((sketch) => {
  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(700, 410, this.WEBGL);
  };
});
```

Demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkpdzeso-having-a-problem-loading-setting-webgl-to-the)

Comment: interesting.  Importing it that way into my component causes a TS1192 error saying `module ........ has no default export` pointing to the P5 folder in the node modules.

Comment: ok I just noticed in your stackblitz up above the `@Component` you declare `WEBGL` as a variable.  I tried that and am still getting an error telling me WEBGL isn't a part of my component.  When I take off `this` and let it target the `WEBGL` variable decalred at the top, it throws another error saying WEBGL is undefined... which is because it doesn't `=` anything.  How does your `console.log(this.WEBGL)` return `webgl` when you're not assigning anything to it?  What is it attached to and how?

Comment: Ive updated the answer to fix the TS1192 error. You need to use `this.WEBGL` and not `WEBGL` and also for your `p.setup` function dont use the arrow notation, use the function keyword, because the context of `this` is important in this use case

Comment: I also removed the webgl declaration in the stackblitz as its not necessary

Comment: I haven't accepted this as the answer yet because I've run into another issue and have been wondering if I should update/change this question or start a new one.  For starters I made the suggested change to my `tsconfig.json` file and I still couldn't import the p5 library the way you suggested, however changing the function syntax and adding `this.` made it work.  I'll continue in another comment.

Comment: I ran into the same issue again with trying to set the angle mode to degrees which is done with `angleMode(DEGREES);` which again refers to a variable inside the scope of `p5.js` and seeing that it's not being scoped into a function that ultimately generates inside the `p5` scope adding `this.` still makes it look for it somewhere within the component.  I'm wondering if this is due to me still importing it as `import * as p5 from 'p5'` or if this really is a scoping issue using it with Angular regardless to which way it's imported.

Comment: Also I tried adding the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` to both the TS compiler options and the Angular compiler options in my `tsconfig.json` file and neither of them allowed me to use the import syntax you suggested.

Comment: could you update the question with the way the code is at now, or if you can share the actual repo?

Comment: Just realised that `esModuleInterop` is also required to be true